# how to display python list in django template

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django. I want to know how can I dispaly python list in django template. The list is a list of days in weeks e.g day_list = ['sunday','monday','tuesday']

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass it to the template as a context and then simply iterate over it.

```
{% for day in day_list %}
    {{ day }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is the [documentation for the `for` tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-for).  I recommend you go through the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/), and in [part 3](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial03/) they go over passing stuff to your templates, including iterating over sequences of stuff (like lists).

Comment: what if i just want to print monday??

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it in the template context.

```
render_to_response(..., {"day_list": ['sunday','monday','tuesday']} )
```